# Sort strings having numbers and characters

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have set of strings like this.

```
1 Wednesday, 3 Monday, 1 2 Tuesday
```

Now I need to sort these considering only letters. The results will be

```
3 Monday, 1 2 Tuesday, 1 Wednesday
```

The strings are sorted by considering substrings (Wednesday, Monday, Tuesday) so I got the result. How I can do that ?

Comment: Are these string representation of dates?

Answer (score 0):

Use compareOptions, remove kCFCompareNumerically in options.

See next url:
[Sorting Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/Articles/ComparingAndSearching.html)

or try this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

@autoreleasepool {

    NSArray *stringsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             @"string 1",
                             @"String 21",
                             @"string 12",
                             @"String 11",
                             @"String 02", nil];
    static NSStringCompareOptions comparisonOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch |
    NSWidthInsensitiveSearch | NSForcedOrderingSearch;
    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSComparator finderSort = ^(id string1, id string2) {
        NSRange string1Range = NSMakeRange(0, [string1 length]);
        return [string1 compare:string2 options:comparisonOptions range:string1Range locale:currentLocale];
    };

    NSArray* sortedArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:finderSort];
    NSLog(@"finderSort: %@", sortedArray);        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSArray *array = @[@"1 Wednesday",@"3 Monday",@"1 2 Tuesday"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEEE"];

NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSCharacterSet *validCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet *unwantedCharecterSet = [validCharacterSet invertedSet];
    NSString *string1 = [(NSString *)obj1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:unwantedCharecterSet];
    NSString *string2 = [(NSString *)obj2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:unwantedCharecterSet];

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string2];

    return [date1 compare:date2];

}];
```

**(
    "3 Monday",
    "1 2 Tuesday",
    "1 Wednesday"
)**

Comment: they are not dates. just sample strings separated by number

Comment: @rakeshNS your question is misleading then, I assumed you wanted to sort based on the weekdays. Can you provide more clarification to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Or, if the string you want to sort with is **always** the last string (and there **always** is one last string) you can just write a comparator that sorts on the last string:

```
NSComparator lastStringSort = ^(id string1, id string2)
{
    NSArray* string1Components = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSArray* string2Components = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    return [[string1Components lastObject] compareToString:[string2Components lastObject]];
};

NSArray* sortedArray = [stringsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:lastStringSort];
```